# rails_3_question :as => why is my /posts/new routing to posts/show after setting up a slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, slug

I'm using Rails 3 and after setting up slugs,  I found that posts/new no longer works.

`posts/:id`, `posts/:id/edit` and all the other CRUD operations work.

However `/posts/new` gives me a routing error

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}

Now for some reason `posts/new` is routing to `posts#show`.  In my routes, its just

```
resources :posts
```

My theory is that since `/posts/:slug` now matches against things other than numbers ids,  the show verb is being routed to first.  However it doesn't make sense since `posts/grr` a nonexistent entry gives a different error than `posts/new` and `posts/first` comes out just fine with all its associated paths working fine as well.

Anyone know what might be going on?

I've uploaded the repo to https://github.com/cultofmetatron/cassowary/tree/photogallary

I know my code sucks,  I'm still learning the ins and outs of the system and I'd appreciate any insight into whats going on.

Comment: I think your theory is right -- chances are it's falling back on posts#show since that would (otherwise) be the index page (that is, just `/posts` would handle posts#show).  That is, it looks for a record whose slug is "new", and doesn't find it.  How did you set up slugs (gem, or roll your own?) -- a gem likely has some routing magic that might not be evident in `routes.rb`.  Run `rake routes` to see what Rails thinks are valid path patterns.  (Oh, PS, awesome title for the question :-)

Comment: haha yes, I was hoping someone would notice. :P

Comment: (thx,  I was hoping someone would notice.  

anyways, I rolled it from scratch to learn how its done.  I add a url_slug string added to the post model and added @post.url_slug to each of the rout helper methods.  it works on edit, index and show but not on new.  and thats the weird thing.

Comment: I added an answer which might be relatively close to correct.  Please try it out and see where I messed up, then I'll edit to make it right, and that way next time I need to do this, I'll remember ... and who knows, maybe someone else will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment the first part seems fine: add a column to the Post column called `slug` and so on, and the contents of that will become some or all of the URL used to display a specific post. (I'll assume the other CRUD operations should work as normal)

To find the URL, the router has to know how to know which controller and action will handle this URL (as compared to others).  A normal `resources :posts` route will match all of the RESTful methods, e.g. mapping a GET request onto a path starting with the controller name, and if an id is specified (`/posts/1`) map to the `posts#show` controller method, if not, it will map to `posts#index` method.  If the request is a PUT, or DELETE or POST, different actions around  a standardized URL format will occur.

Two changes are needed:

1. URL with the post slug format needs to map to the `posts#show` method (which is modified accordingly), and
2. Any links to the `show` page that are generated on your site need to use the post slug instead of the id

I'll assume you're OK with URLs start with `/posts` (if not, you'll need to identify some other unique pattern).

The first change requires that you override the specific case of the show method using route globbing, my adding something like `match 'posts/*slug` *before* the standard resource route.  Here's a link to the guide on route globbing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing

The next change, modify the existing `posts#show` method so that it looks for `slug` instead of `id`, e.g.

```
def show
  @post = Post.where("slug = ?", params[:slug])
  ...
end
```

Finally, change the way Rails handles the URL helper `posts_path`.  Do this by overriding `to_param` in your Post model, e.g.

```
def to_param
  "/posts/#{slug}"
end
```

And then you're done.  Maybe.

After that, see how the friendly_id gem does the same thing :-) https://github.com/norman/friendly_id